# which is more efficient, for loop or just regular adding

Tags: c, performance, for-loop

I am developing a c app which reads data from a mysql table,process it and then inserts it in to 100 different tables in a oracle database. The thing is there is a huge concern for the performance of the app. In the mysql table I mentioned ,there are 4,800,000 and there are 92 columns in it. 90 of theme are just integers. So in my app for each entry of  4,800,000 , I'm running a for loop as given below.

```
    for (col = 1; col < 92; col++) {
        if (row[col] != NULL) {
            sum += strtol(row[col], NULL, 10);
        } else
            sum = sum + 0;
        if (col == 14) {
            p1_2weeks = sum;
        } else if (col == 31) {
            p2_1month = sum;
        } else if (col == 90) {
            p3_2month = sum;
        }
    }
```

So since this runs that much of iterations I believe there might be a possibility that I would be able to reduce the time taken by using regular addition to do this like.

```
 p1_2weeks = strtol(row[1], NULL, 10) +
             strtol(row[2], NULL, 10) +
             ... +
             strtol(row[14], NULL, 10);
 p2_1months = p1_2weeks +
             strtol(row[15], NULL, 10) + 
             ... +
             strtol(row[31], NULL, 10);
 p3_3months = p2_1months +
             strtol(row[32], NULL, 10) +
             ... +
             strtol(row[91], NULL, 10);
```

So can someone suggest which one is better or some other way of doing this right.

Comment: `row[col] != NULL`...smells fishy...

Comment: thats because I had to ignore the null values before they are added. Any sugessions on that too. @SouravGhosh

Comment: No offense, do you know what `NULL` means (type), anyway?

Comment: NULL means there is nothing. I did'nt had a way of reading it from the database. So I had to use it. any idea on that please

Comment: Ummm. basically, NULL is a pointer, so you can't compare that against an `int` (I suppose). Enable compiler warnings....

Comment: But this worked. will this cause future errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98772/discussion-between-laksith-and-sourav-ghosh).

Comment: IF you do a direct sum in opposite order, you can save some calculations by re-using previous results: calculate `p1_2weeks = strtol(row[1], NULL, 10) + ... + strtol(row[14], NULL, 10);` first, then `p2_1months = p1_2weeks + strtol(row[15], NULL, 10) + ... strtol(row[31], NULL, 10);` and finally `p3_3months = p2_1months + strtol(row[32], NULL, 10) + ... strtol(row[91], NULL, 10);`. However if you expect `row[col] == NULL`, which case you handle in the loop, how would you handle it in a direct summation?

Comment: @SouravGhosh `row[col]` is being passed as the first argument to `strtol`, which means it must be of type `char *`. Hence, comparing with `NULL` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @CiaPan yeah. Sorry thats what I had in mind. But I wrote another thing.thankz again. I ve edited the code according to your sugesstion

Comment: @SouravGhosh: `row[col]` is a pointer to a string, it is `NULL` if the database column is a `NULL` value.  The OP tests for `NULL` values in the loop but not in the additions...  one of several inconsistencies in this code.

Comment: I'd be more worried about the fact that you're inserting data into 100 tables than the performance of `for` loops in C.  The time taken to stuff the data into the database probably dwarfs the time taken in these loops.  At the least, you should have concrete evidence that these loops are an issue before optimizing them.

Comment: It is not meaningful to discuss manual optimization of this code without a specific system in mind.

Comment: Let's say the bottleneck of your code isn't the database transactions part. I would go with chqrlie's recommends. I want to add two things: 1. unrolling a loop with too many iterations may be slower, as the processor will need to read new instructions from cache or main memory. 2. Keeping the first one in mind, i would try to change the unroll count and find the optimum one for your CPU. probably it's value between 1 and 16.

Comment: @seleciii44: instead of unrolling the loop by hand, I would trust the compiler  to do it automatically if it so decides for `-O3`.  Your remark on the extra code size is quite pertinent, but if the code were the bottleneck, it would be executed many times and stay in the rather large cache current processors now have.

Comment: @chrqlie: i have seen examples that unrolling by hand beats the compiler. I'm assuming -o3 is being used anyway. By the way on some dsp's (Texas Instruments for example) there is a pragma which you can explicitly set the unroll count. To conclude, if i need something really fast i would see if doing by hand is better or not. If not i would definitely leave it to compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `for` loop or manual unrolling with explicit additions is not going to make a significant difference.  Most of the time will be spent reading from MySQL and converting fields to strings, and inserting the result into Oracle. If the program spends 99% of the time in the database code, which would not surprise me, optimizing this loop would be a moot point.

You might want to look for an different method for extracting values from MySQL that does not convert integers to strings.

Profiling will tell you where the bottleneck is for a given combination of compiler / options / cpu / memory / dataset, but it might be tricky to tell time spent in your program and time spent waiting for the Oracle process or the MySQL connection.  Elapsed time is the final judge.

Note that your proposed alternative is not semantically equivalent: in the sequence of explicit additions, you do not test for `NULL` fields. If the columns cannot be `NULL`, you can remove the `if (row[col] != NULL)` test, if they can be `NULL`, you must modify the addition to add more tests, which will make it very clumsy. In addition, as seleciii44 suggests, the proposed alternative generates much larger code, which has an impact as well.

Node also that the loop is very straightforward, whereas the sequence of additions is error prone: it is easy to make cut and paste errors and miss an index or duplicate one. If you go for the additions, use a code layout that makes the indices stand out clearly.  Look at how I reformated your code.

Indeed you have typos in the loop (`p2_1month`/`p2_1months`, `p3_2month`/`p3_3months`) and the addition does not compute `p3_3months` the same way: the loop sums `90` days, where the addition sums `91` days.  But of course the number of days in a quarter varies, from `89` to `92` days.

Note also that `sum = sum + 0;` is a no op that should be removed, but the compiler most likely will not generate code for it.

If you are concerned with the extra tests for 14, 31 and 90 days performed for each iteration, you can use this:

```
    long temp[92];
    for (col = 1; col < 92; col++) {
        if (row[col] != NULL) {
            sum += strtol(row[col], NULL, 10);
        }
        temp[col] = sum;
    }
    p1_2weeks = temp[14];
    p2_1month = temp[31];
    p3_3months = temp[90];
```

It may be more efficient than the version with tests, but only careful benchmarking will tell you, because modern processors' branch prediction will minimize the cost if these tests while storing `91` values into a local array is a small extra cost.

By the way, are you sure about `col < 92`? Your loop treats `91` columns, but you write that only `90` of the `92` columns are integers.

Again, I would first look for a method for extracting values from MySQL as integers.

Comment: Is there a way of directly getting inigers from mysql. which would be more efficient?

Comment: A good and easy metric may be to check the CPU usage of the program, if it's significantly below 100% it's probably waiting for MySQL most of the time.

Comment: I do think this is the first thing the OP should do (retrieve numeric types instead of strings), hence I upvoted. However, the question is whether manual additions are faster than loops :P

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that writing the additions yourself is going to make this any faster. But optimization is not made with guesses, it's made with measurements.

What I would comment about your code is:

```
else
   sum = sum + 0;
```

I hope your compiler get rid of this thing, otherwise you're just wasting time here.

```
        if (col == 14) {
            p1_2weeks = sum;
        } else if (col == 31) {
            p2_1month = sum;
        } else if (col == 90) {
            p3_2month = sum;
        }
```

Although branch prediction can help you a lot here, maybe it would be better to move this out of the for-loop. You can do it separating in several loops with each partial computation in the middle.
(loop until 14, assign p1_2weeks, loop until 31, save p2_1month ...)

Comment: so you mean that there is no need of a else part. is it ?

Comment: I guess `sum` is some numeric type, so setting `sum = sum + 0` is the same as `sum = sum` which does nothing.

Comment: It's going to make it slower, since it's going to be `strtol` doiminated and as @CiaPan points out, the proposed unroll makes many more of them. 90-odd  (or more) `strtol` calls are going to turn a couple of int adds and comparisons, however you do them, into near-immesurable noise.

Comment: @pvg what I propose won't increase the amount of `strtol`, but I believe that indeed the difference may be negligible. This would just save some equality tests.

Comment: @VillasV no (and you're right, I was unclear), but what the OP is proposing does. Either way, since the end result involves shoveling all this crap into another db, none of this will probably make any difference at all. Might as well write it in ruby with 7 layers of metaprogramming indirection.

Answer (score 3):

The only reasonable answer to a question like this is to profile it. Write it in the way that makes the most intuitive sense and then see if it adds up to a significant amount of time worth spending the time optimizing and then debugging all of your optimizations.

Comment: Indeed and chances are this is going to be so dominated by `strtol` (let alone the query and insert times) that hand-unrolling that loop will make exactly zero difference.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you @pvg

Comment: @Laksith basically, do what both answers tell you and measure first. The optimizations you are thinking of are very unlikely to make any difference.

Comment: Compilers these days are very very good and computer architectures are very very complicated. It's not impossible, but it is hard to do better than the compiler.

Comment: I agree with @Turn. Although we can't guarantee by simple reasoning, it's very unlikely that manually writing a loop is going to give any performance gains. I think he would at most make the compiler's life harder.

Comment: The other thing is that 4 million+ inserts (or more? to 100 tables?) is surely going to end up doing i/o and make everything else, including a 4+ million row read from a db with hot caches look instant.

Answer (score 2):

Unrolling the loop may afford a small advantage by removing the loop overhead, however this would only be an advantage if the loop were *very large* and the operations within it were *very simple*, and neither is true in this instance.

Addition is a *very simple* operation (one machine instruction), but you are missing the *elephant in the room* that is `strtol()` - there you have a function call overhead plus whatever is required to convert a string to an integer which will be *many* machine instructions (in a loop too).

Moreover the compiler optimiser is quite capable of performing loop unrolling for itself if there is some likely significant advantage.  So this kind of hand-written micro-optimisation is almost always futile, and renders the code unreadable and difficult to maintain.  You would do better to consider overall design and algorithm complexity and let the compiler do *its* job.

In any event, given that this is a database application it will do doubt be largely bound to disk and/or network performance, and *any* code optimisation may be insignificant overall.  A fast server and plenty of RAM may accelerate your application to a far greater extent than code optimisation of *any* kind.